# How to get validations in user control and main page to show up together?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a web page with various fields and various validators. Also on this page is a user control with several validators.

When I submit the form, if there are errors on the fields in the user control, these are displayed, but errors on the main form are not.

For example, the form is displayed. Let's say I leave everything blank and submit. I get "required field errors" for missing fields on the user control, but I get no errors for missing fields on the main form. Then let's say I fill in valid values on all the fields that are on the user control and submit again. NOW I get errors for missing fields on the main form.

Perhaps I should note that I have a ValidationSummary on the main form, and none in the user control. The errors from the user control are appearing in the ValidationSummary on the main page.

If it matters, the validators in the user control are all custom validators with the code in the user control.

How do I get all errors to display at once?

*Update*

I put together a trivial form with one text box in the main page, and then one control which contains one text box, and a required field validator on each, and a submit button, and that was it. This worked the way I wanted: If I left both blank and clicked Submit, I got both error messages.

So the principle works like I want. Apparently there's something about my particular page that doesn't work. And that's dozens of fields and several layers of controls and hundreds of lines of code. I'm not going to post all that and expect the friendly folks here to hack through it. (And I'd be giving away a bunch of my company's real code.)

So if someone on here can say, "Oh yeah, if you have a validator whose ID rhymes with 'foobar' then it doesn't work", or some such issue, please shout it out. Otherwise ... if I find what's causing me grief, I'll post something.

Comment: Give them all the same `ValidationGroup` name. They do not get renamed like the ID and will work across multiple different controls.

Comment: @vdwwd Hmm, I tried that. Still no.

Comment: Strange, I tested it just now and it worked just fine. All validators across multiple UC and the page they are on fired together.

Comment: Maye some other javascript code is interferring. Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @vdwwd Well, if it works for you at least that means that the principle works, and that there's just something happening to mess it up. I'm not getting any JS errors. It's a complex page, master page, main page, several controls, controls inside controls. So maybe I just need to set up a simple test case and build from there.

Comment: Ooh, just hit me. JS shouldn't matter as I'm doing all server-side validation. I wonder if client-side works and server-side doesn't.

Comment: And, is that the case?

Comment: @VDWWD No, that wasn't it. See my update, though.